# Mechanical simulation does not stabilize around equilibrium point

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, equilibrium, software

There is a classical problem which is a bead in a vertical hoop that is rotating around its vertical axis. If $R$ is the radius of the hoop, $m$ the mass of the bead, $\omega$ the angular velocity of the hoop and $\theta$ the angle that represents the position of the bead measured from the bottom, the lagrangian is $$L = \dfrac{1}{2} m R^2 (\dot\theta^2 + \omega^2 \sin^2\theta) - mgR(1 - \cos\theta)$$ and the equation of motion is therefore $$ \ddot{\theta} = \sin\theta \left( \omega^2 \cos\theta - \dfrac{g}{R} \right)\ . $$

There are many equilibrium points. One of them is the angle that fulfils $$\cos\theta = \dfrac{g}{R\omega^2}\ ,$$ and as far I could research, this point is stable if $$\omega > \sqrt{\dfrac{g}{R}}\ .$$

I want to do a simulation of the system starting at $\theta_0 = \pi/6$, and making it evolve to $\theta = \pi/3$. In this case $\cos\theta = 1/2$, and I should apply an a angular velocity $$\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{2g}{R}} > \sqrt{\dfrac{g}{R}}\ ,$$ so there should not be any stability problems. In order to make that simulation, I used the following system:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l} \dot{\theta_1} = \theta_2 \\ \dot{\theta_2} = \sin\theta_1 \left( \omega^2 \cos\theta_1 - \dfrac{g}{R} \right) \end{array}\right.
$$

I wrote the following code for the simulation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as sci


G = 9.82
L = 1
OMEGA = np.sqrt(2 * G / L)
THETA_0 = np.pi / 6

SIM_TIME = 10


def watt(theta, t):
    dtheta0 = theta[1]
    dtheta1 = np.sin(theta[0]) * (np.cos(theta[0]) * OMEGA ** 2 - G / L)

    return [dtheta0, dtheta1]


time = np.arange(0, SIM_TIME, 0.001)
result = sci.odeint(watt, [THETA_0, 0], time)
theta = result[:, 0]

plt.plot(time, [np.pi / 3] * len(time), '--')
plt.plot(time, theta)
plt.show()
```

But I never get the system to stabilize. Here is the result of the simulation:
[image]

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about debugging code and algorithms, not physics.

Comment: Also, it never stabilizes because there isn't any damping. The issue of stability is actually that of a response to _small_ perturbations, so what you need to do is start with various values for $\theta$ and run the simulation by applying a small value for $\dot \theta$ initially. When the result changes drastically between two close-by angles, you have found the critical angle.

Comment: It is very instructive and important to understand the difference between stability and asymptotic stability of an equillibirum point of a system. In this case, the dynamics near the equilibrium state you are simulating is stable, but not asymptotically stable. This is because the system is conservative (conserves energy) and possesses a first integral of motion (the energy, i.e. the Hamiltonian).

Answer (score 1):

As inspired by the the previous answer, I had added a damping force proportional to velocity in the equation of motion. Recreating in Mathematica,

```
R = 1;
G = 9.81;
\[Omega] = Sqrt[2*G/R];
\[Mu] = 0.3;
ode1 = {y''[t] == Sin[y[t]]*((\[Omega]^2)*Cos[y[t]] - G/R) - \[Mu]*y'[t], y[0] == Pi/6, y'[0] == 0}
sol = NDSolve[ode1, y, {t, 0, 15}]
Plot[{y[t] /. sol, y = Pi/3}, {t, 0, 15}]
```

the modeled solution does indeed converge as expected.
[image]

Comment: your damping $\mu\,\dot y$ should be $\frac{\mu}{m}\,\dot y$

Comment: @Eli Yes it should, but you can handwave the mass to be 1?

Comment: Or the mu is mu per mass

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in a small damping force, proportional to $-\dot{\phi}$. Note that it is small but also present in the real world. I am too lazy to calculate, just estimate how much friction there would be based on a typical force and friction coefficient.